# How come canPlayType('video/mov') returns an empty string, but I can still play the video?

Tags: html5-video

I'm on chrome 80, and I'm able to get an html5 video tag to play a .mov file without any trouble. However, `canPlayType('video/mov')`, `canPlayType('video/quicktime')`, and `canPlayType('video/x-quicktime')` all return `""`. `canPlayType('video/mp4')`, `canPlayType('video/ogg')`, `canPlayType('video/webm')` are all working as expected, however (they at least return `"maybe"`). Why doesn't this work as expected for any of the mov formats, and since I can clearly play an mov, is there another way I can programmatically, reliably tell this is true? I understand this checking is all a little iffy, (hence "maybe" and "probably"), but is it really *this* iffy? I'd love to at least see some documentation that actually says "sometimes canPlayType() will literally return `""` even though you can actually play videos of that type. Sorry, that's as good as it gets."

Here's my checking code:

```
const video = document.createElement('video');

const canPlay = {
    mp4: video.canPlayType('video/mp4'),
    ogg: video.canPlayType('video/ogg'),
    webm: video.canPlayType('video/webm'),
    mov: video.canPlayType('video/mov'),
    avi: video.canPlayType('video/avi'),
};

console.log(canPlay);
// outputs: { mp4: "maybe", ogg: "maybe", webm: "maybe", mov: "", avi: "" }
```

Comment: I've reported this as a bug on Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1120292

Comment: It returns the same for Firefox too.

Comment: The Chromium bug has been closed as WontFix: "Closing out old issues due to departures. Please reply if this is still an issue for you."
Am assuming I can't play .mov in my browser because I'm on Windows, so if this is still an issue on (I assume) Mac, hopefully someone else will test.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string (`''`) is considered a falsy value in JavaScript, so when coerced to a boolean equals false.  canPlayType() returns a string, so it's kind of a hacky way in my opinion to allow it to work in conditionals.

You could use the Boolean() function on the result or create a short circuit to false if you want to console.log() the booleean state.

That being said, as to why it can still play the format we'll need input from another person because I don't know.  It's the same for me when I play FLAC files.  Browser says they aren't supported but it still plays them just fine.